# Removing junk from JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, jsonp

For IE7 and IE8, I am capturing some JSONp to use in my webpage.  Below is an extract of the JSONP:

```
{
    class: "min-temp",
    span: {
        class: "units-values temperature-units-values",
        span: [
            {
                class: "units-value temperature-value temperature-value-unit-c",
                span: {
                    class: "unit",
                    content: "°C"
                },
                content: "11
              "
            },
            {
                class: "units-value temperature-value temperature-value-unit-f",
                span: {
                    class: "unit",
                    content: "°F"
                },
                content: "52
              "
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

If you look at the `content: "11` and `content: "52`, you will see that there are a lot of extra characters after them.  How do I remove those extra characters so I only end up with the number, i.e. `11` or `52`.

At the moment, I am extracting those numbers as follows:

`day.span[1].span.span[0].content` gives me `11` and `day.span[1].span.span[1].content` gives me `52`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have pointed out that I need this to work on IE7 and IE8.  Does .trim() still apply?

Comment: Or `parseInt` if you're expecting a number every time.

Comment: try using parseInt() if it is integer all the way.

Comment: @Brad, I don't have any control of the JSON data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only expect integer values there, just use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). It will ignore whitespaces.

Comment: Don't forget to specify a radix, in case the number starts with `0` or `0x`: `parseInt(' 52   ', 10)`.

Answer (score 1):

If they're always expected to be numeric, you could `parseInt` or `parseFloat` the `content`, or as @Pointy suggested, you could use `$.trim()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to trim anything that is not a number.

```
content = content.replace(/\D/g, '');
```